# KeyBinding style

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, key-bindings

I use an ICommand class similar to RelayCommand and similar variations of that, but with extended properties that tend to go with a command. In addition to setting such properties as part of the Command setup, I can use them when binding. For example

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Key="{Binding SaveCommand.GestureKey}" Modifiers="{Binding SaveCommand.GestureModifier}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Now what I would like to do is have a style to take advantage of this, something like the code below. It doesn't work though, since apparently KeyBinding doesn't have a DataContext. Is there someway I can make this binding or something similar to it work?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
<Style x:Key="KeyBindingStyle" TargetType="{x:Type KeyBinding}">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
    <Setter Property="Gesture" Value="{Binding GestureKey}" />
    <Setter Property="Modifiers" Value="{Binding GestureModifier}" />
</Style>

<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding DataContext="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

## UPDATE

Below is a first pass at extending KeyBinding along the lines that H.B. is suggesting, along with the basic structure of my extended Command class. The binding doesn't compile with this error: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'CommandReference' property of type 'KeyBindingEx'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <cmdRef:KeyBindingEx  CommandReference="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>

   public class KeyBindingEx : KeyBinding
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandReferenceProperty = DependencyProperty
        .Register("VmCommand", typeof(CommandReference), typeof(KeyBindingEx),          
                  new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCommandReferenceChanged)));

    private static void OnCommandReferenceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var kb = (KeyBinding) d;
        var cmdRef = (VmCommand)e.NewValue;

        kb.Key = cmdRef.GestureKey;
        kb.Modifiers = cmdRef.GestureModifier;
        kb.Command = cmdRef;
    }

    public CommandReference CommandReference
    {
        get { return (CommandReference)GetValue(CommandReferenceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandReferenceProperty, value); }
    }
} 

public class CommandReference : PropertyChangedBase, ICommandReference
{

    public Key GestureKey
    {
        get { return _gestureKey; }
        set
        {
            if (_gestureKey == value) return;

            _gestureKey = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => GestureKey);
        }
    }
    private Key _gestureKey;

    ...
}


public class VmCommand : CommandReference, ICommand
{
    ...

    public KeyBinding ToKeyBinding()
    {
        return new KeyBinding
               {
                   Command = this, 
                   Key = GestureKey, 
                   Modifiers = GestureModifier
               };
   }

}
```

Comment: You want something compatible with the restrictions of Silverlight, right? (Edit: Those Setter.Value bindings seem to suggest otherwise...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you could either create a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) which does all the assignments for you or you subclass KeyBinding with a new property of your custom command type which should hook up a property changed callback in which then again can set the other properties. Cannot think of anything more elegant than that right now.

Comment: Hello! Extending KeyBinding feels more comfortable to me since I have used this class to create KeyBindings in code before, and my next MarkUpExtension will be my first.
But my first attempt at this is no good at all. Can you take a look at my edited post and get me pointed in a better direction?

Comment: You register the dependency property under a different name than what you use, that string `"VmCommand"` in the register method should be `"CommandReference"`.