# How to add set of keys to keybinding in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, key-bindings

I need to add set of keys to the keybinding in wpf.
So any ways of adding list of key bindings in a one place or best practises ?

eg-

```html
<KeyBinding Key={Binding Converter={StaticResource converter},Command="{Binding MyCommand}"}
```

Comment: what are you trying for: you mean add a keyboard short cut like `Ctrl + A` to Select All ? or something else ?

Comment: Yes adding short cut keys.Adding more short cut keys, such as Ctrl+H, Enter , ESC and etc .So i have a huge list of short cuts to add as keybindings.So need to declare all short cut keys in a one place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KeyBinding style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364640/keybinding-style)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6364640/2470362) will help you

Comment: Thank you Mathew .I will try this

Comment: I have tried this one but it doesn't able to fix my issue.So i need to use only one key binding and attach other all key bindings to it according to the key press.